# qnx os learning path & automated drive

Tags: qnx, blackberry-qnx, qnx-ifs

I am flutter developer and i think to learn qnx os and its automation usage and etc ;
I search lot about it and , but did't found something good about it;

Please provide me a Learning path to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QNX® Software Development Platform User's Guide
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/
http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/